# How can get unlimited levels of menu in laravel which i have saved

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
Products Table
    id  | name                          | project_id | paren_id
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    1   | ParentProduct                 | 1          | NULL
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    2   | TopLevelOneProduct            | NULL       | 1
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    3   | ToplevelOneProductChildFolder | NULL       | 2
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    4   | TopLevelOneChildSubChildFolder| NULL       | 3      
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    5   | TopLevelTwoProduct            | NULL       | 1

Categories Table
    id  | product_id     | name                             
    ---------------------------------------------------
    1   | 2              | TopLevelCategory                 
    ---------------------------------------------------
    2   | 3              | TopLevelOneProduct           
    ---------------------------------------------------
    3   | 4              | TopLevelOneChildSubChildRequest  
    ---------------------------------------------------
    4   | 1              | TopLevelProductCategory
```

```
D
├── E
│   ├── A
│   │   └── B
│   └── C   
└── G
    ├── F
    └── H
```

I want to like this tree because I have a parent-child relationship with unlimited levels of children & sub-child with categories on different levels. My mean is that One Product will have Childs and these Childs will have SubChilds & these SubChilds will have SubSubChilds... many more on a different level.

Please give me a solution so that could understand this logic and solve this

Answer (score 2):

I think you are in search of these tree type of structure.click below link.

http://home.jejaju.com/play/nested%20ul%20with%20checkboxes

This is done with jquery  built in functions parent() and parents().if This is relevent to your requirement. this is it.

Comment: Thanks, Dear @rohit for replying to me, I want to get from the database I have saved this type of structure but want to get with parent-child with a tree of unlimited level

Answer (score 0):

You can via this structure to be forced to a unlimited number of parents and children of menus

```
Categories Table
    id  |  name                  |  parent_id                            
    -----------------------------------------
    1   | Category 1             |    0
    -----------------------------------------
    2   | SubCategory            |    1
    -----------------------------------------
    3   | SubSubCategory         |    2
    -----------------------------------------
    4   | SubSubSubCategory      |    3
    -----------------------------------------
    5   | SubSubSubSubCategory   |    4
    -----------------------------------------
    6   | Category 2             |    0
    -----------------------------------------
    7   | SubCategory 2          |    6
    -----------------------------------------
    8   | SubSubCategory 2       |    7
    -----------------------------------------
    9   | SubSubSubCategory 2    |    8
    -----------------------------------------
    10  | SubSubSubSubCategory 2 |    9


Products Table
    id  |  name                |  category_id                            
    -----------------------------------------
    1   | Products 1           |    2
    -----------------------------------------
    2   | Products 2           |    3
    -----------------------------------------
    3   | Products 3           |    4
```

Comment: Thanks, Dear @muhamedyahya, Yes you are right I'm searching this type that one parent will have sub-sub child & these sub child will have sub child mean that unlimited level from top to end on every stage